# How to make a Tkinter Text Box have a height of 2 but center the text vertically?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to have my tkinter textbox have a height of 2, but center the text vertically. I have tried adding a tag_configuration, but it does not seem to have worked. I have been searching on this site and only found ways to center horizontally, not vertically.  Any help is appreciated.

```
        entry = tk.Text(self.frame, height=2, width=20, font=('Corsiva Hebrew', '20'), borderwidth=3,
                             relief='solid')
        entry.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `spacing1` and `spacing3` options to some value (in pixels) and set `height=1` instead.

Below is an example:

```py
entry = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=20, spacing1=20, spacing3=20,
                font=('Corsiva Hebrew', '20'), bd=3, relief='solid')
entry.tag_configure('center', justify='center')
entry.insert('end', 'Hello World', 'center')
```

And output:

[image]